# Is there a way to find all uses of a field in mail templates and other sources?

Tags: email-template, fields, search

How do I find all the uses of a field beyond just Apex classes?

Comment: Gusk, please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, what you've tried that didn't work, code you've written, & where you're stuck, etc., the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of metadata search engines that will do what you're asking. Which one to use would be up to you. Some need to be installed in the org, others run as plug-ins from Chrome and there are some that can be run externally to query your org. One of the latter would be Cloudingo Studio from Symphonic Source (free). I think FuseIT SFDC Explorer will also do the same (again free).

The App Exchange Packages can be found by simply using the search keyword Metadata where you'll apps like [Octopus](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5cEKEAZ) (free) and others should pop up in the results. SF Quick Metadata Lookup is one of the Chrome Plugins I'm aware of that may do the trick for you.